# SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server

Hola estoy intentando entrar al Reporting Service pero al momento de ingresar a la pagina me pide usuario y contraseña y todos los tutoriales que he visto entran sin estos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tablien ya intente con varias configuraciones de credenciales y no me deja, no se que estoy haciendo mal :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las credenciales que estás cambiando son las que usa para conectarse a la base de datos. Lo que necesitas es el usuario para el sitio de configuración, pero eso no recuerdo donde se definen fuera del instalador.

Comment: Lo pide 2 veces? porque en la primera pantalla pregunta por la instancia, usuario y contraseña y en la segunda es la imagen que muestro

Comment: Buscar `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` y configurar la cuenta pa acceder a eso; esos datos se guardan en vaaarias partes y mover una sola cosa potencialmente va a dañar todo. Ahí va a preguntar si se elige una cuenta de Windows, si se crea una nueva, etc. [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-the-report-server-service-account-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16)